# sbt 0.13.15 override runTask in play project

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to create a custom `runTask` for a play project with sbt 0.13.15. I'm wondering if this is possible.

The `sbt` documentation suggests using `fullRunTask` to define a custom run task, but I'd really just like to add another task to execute before `sbt run` (i.e. `run` depends on this custom task).

Overall goal is to create a task that transpiles some javascript whenever `sbt run` is invoked.

I honestly cannot find a way to make the current `runTask` depend on my custom `fooTask`.

This is what I'm trying:

```
lazy val playProject = (project in file("somePlayProject"))
    .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
    .settings(//some common settings and library deps)
    .settings(
        run in Compile := {
            val jsTranspile: Seq[String] = Seq("bash", "-c", "commands", "to", "transpile")
            jsTranspile !
            (run in Compile).evaluated
        }
    )
```

Unfortunately, this just runs the normal `sbt run` for a play project. If I remove the `(run in Compile).evaluate` command, then the `jsTranspile` task runs successfully. I'm not sure how to harmonize the two.